# ImageMagick: use multiple cores with convert and montage on macOSX?

Tags: bash, macos, parallel-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using montage and convert utilities in my bash scripts to convert, process or combine images in the following fashion:

```
for file in "${vizu_temp}"/*.png; do
    convert ${some+options} $file $file
  done
```

how could I improve my bash workflow in order that I could use multiple cores available on my Imac to speed up such post-processing ?

In particularly I am using '-distort BarrelInverse 2:20' option as the pre-processing filter that takes a lot of time for a big image ..

Comment: What have you searched for and what have you tried?  You might look into `find` with `xargs` or `parallel`.

Comment: You should consider using the newer `magick` command rather than `convert`. You would need to give a more representative example of your actual code, and your images and how many you are processing if you want a sensible answer.